# How to uninstall SSMS 19.1 completely with absolutely all settings?

Tags: ssms

SSMS 19.1.56.0 English-US
Windows 10.0.19044

I want to remove it absolutely completely with all settings. After a re-install, it should behave like installing on a fresh computer.

Currently, when I uninstall it and re-install, then for example, it still keeps the settings of the tools windows layout and the default server. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Really, all you need is for someone to know where the prefs are kept - then all you need do is delete them. No reinstall needed.

Comment: @Tetsujin yes okay but where do I find them?

Comment: That's the question you need to be asking. I've no clue, otherwise I'd have said so;) Probably in %APPDATA%, though there may be bits stored in the registry too. I don't know the app at all, so I can't guess any better.

Answer (score -2):

I use Regedit and seek out and remove any/all entries that look, smell or sound like the vendor OR program you are trying to get rid of.  Use of Regedit has saved me and my many customers hundreds of reinstall and or upgrade loops for a variety of issues from failed software updates/forced interim pushes by vendors to bad software or driver de-installation practices by you or those vendors.

You basically

1. Use the File, Export keystrokes to BACKUP your current registry - in case you go too far with your REG hacking and need to roll-back and try again, then
2. Use the File, Find keystrokes to seek out, highlight within the Right panel (minor), or Left panel (major) and then delete anything you find in the entire registry that looks like, links to, or IS your errant App, software or driver. Then
3. Press F3 to search again and again until your File, Find word(s) are not found. Then exit Regedit.

Now try whatever was not working.  If it works now, you are done.

If it doesn't, rrelaunch Regedit, BACKUP again using a different NAME, and repeat the entire process again using another word or words under File, Find.

Remember to backup the Registry first under another NAME knowing that you can always roll-back to the REG Backup you saved with that unique NAME by using the File, Import keystrokes and selecting the correct saved REG Backup file/folder.  For the Avast issues mentioned I use vendor or software titles and a sequential number for the filename